# How can I change date stamps in python

Tags: python

how can I convert the date format from

Current format   : [day] [month] [day value] [hour]:[minute]:[second] [time zone difference] [year]

to

New format       : [year]-[month value]-[day value] [hour]:[minute]:[second]

For example, a current format value:

Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020
should be converted to:

2020-02-04 17:04:01

in python

Comment: `datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime("%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %z %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` should do it. See [strftime.org](https://strftime.org/) for an explanation of the format codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parser`. Then use `strftime` to format the `datetime` object

```py
from dateutil import parser

x = 'Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020 '
y = parser.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

```
>>> y
'2020-02-04 17:04:01'
```

> Check out:
>
> http://strftime.net/